# Python multiprocessing shared memory

Tags: python, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing

How does python handles shared memory in multiprocessing from the perspective of operating system.
I mean when we have two python processes and they want to share some variables,
where in the memory are these variables stored, as I read on the internet, the memory is not in the address space of these two processes.

Comment: Of course it's in the address space of the processes. Each OS has a facility for sharing memory between processes. For example, in Unix-likes we can `mmap` memory to share it between processes.

Comment: I don't know how mmap works, could you give me more details about mmap ? or give me a good link for beginners to understand.

Comment: Look at things related to MAP_ANONYMOUS here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

Comment: thanks, I'll read it.

Comment: does it mean that there is a file which these two processes have access to ?
and they see the file content in part of their address space ?

Comment: No, that's why it is anonymous. That parent process creates the anonymous mapping, and after `fork()` the child processes still have access to it. It is anonymous, which means it isn't backed by a file.